# How to prevent FluentValidation from caching the validator class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have the following class

```
[Validator(typeof(MyViewModelValidator)]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}

    public class MyViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyViewModel>
    {
        public MyViewModelValidator()
        {
            //Stuff goes here
        }
    }
}
```

And I have noticed that the Validator constructor only gets called once during my application. This is problematic because I access the HttpContext in the validator. How can I handle this situation ?

Thank you

Comment: This user has solved a similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005146/fluentvalidation-validators-lifecycle-and-using-validators-to-check-against-db

Comment: Thanls, yes I've seen this question but I know that I must not use a singleton. My question here is more : why is my code behaving as a singleton and how can I prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

All right, the answer is [in the source code](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/f0b71ecdf9fde007d73acd10435653336a152a17/src/FluentValidation/Internal/InstanceCache.cs). FluentValidation is caching the instance.

```
public class InstanceCache {
        readonly Dictionary<Type, object> cache = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    readonly object locker = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or creates an instance using Activator.CreateInstance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to instantiate</param>
    /// <returns>The instantiated object</returns>
    public object GetOrCreateInstance(Type type) {
        return GetOrCreateInstance(type, Activator.CreateInstance);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or creates an instance using a custom factory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to instantiate</param>
    /// <param name="factory">The custom factory</param>
    /// <returns>The instantiated object</returns>
    public object GetOrCreateInstance(Type type, Func<Type, object> factory) {
        object existingInstance;

        if(cache.TryGetValue(type, out existingInstance)) {
            return existingInstance;
        }

        lock(locker) {
            if (cache.TryGetValue(type, out existingInstance)) {
                return existingInstance;
            }

            var newInstance = factory(type);
            cache[type] = newInstance;
            return newInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll modify it and recompile from source. I don't want to use IoC to validate attach the validators to my ViewModels, I prefer to have everything defined in the same file for this usage, makes maintenance easier here.

Comment: Hi @readdy, just wondering if there is any possibility of on-demand flushing an existingInstance of a type from the Cache and re-create it. Removing the cache imposes a huge performance impact on the view rendering.